# Android app crashes when using bundle to moving data from one to another using firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, crash, bundle

I am trying to move register number from MainActivity.java to Academics.java
I used navigation drawer to jump from one activity to another.
After using bundle to move data...While clicking  the option on navigation drawer the app crashes. help me.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Bundle bundle;
EditText regno,password;
ProgressDialog progress;
TextView attempt,register;
FirebaseFirestore store;
Button signin;
Integer count=5;
String Re,Pass,dept;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progress=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    store=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    regno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    register=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    attempt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         //progress bar
         progress.setTitle("Please wait");
         progress.setMessage("Fetching Data..");
         progress.show();
         //-----------------
         String INregno=regno.getText().toString();
         String INpass=password.getText().toString();

            if(INregno.isEmpty())
         {
             regno.setError("Enter the Registerno");
             progress.dismiss();
         }
         else if(INpass.isEmpty())
         {
             password.setError("Enter the password");
             progress.dismiss();
         }
            else if(count>=1)
            {
             //Firestore Fetching

             store.collection("Students").document(regno.getText().toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
             {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
                 {

                     Re = documentSnapshot.getString("Regno");
                     Pass = documentSnapshot.getString("Password");
                     dept = documentSnapshot.getString("Department");
                     if (password.getText().toString().equals(Pass) && regno.getText().toString().equals(Re))
                     {
                         finish();
                         progress.dismiss();
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         /*Bundle intent to take data from login to other activity

                          */
                         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Academic.class);
                         in.putExtra("regno",Re);
                         in.putExtra("dept",dept);
                         startActivity(in);
                     }
                     else
                         {
                         --count;
                             progress.dismiss();
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         attempt.setText("No.of.Attempts: "+count);
                         }

                 }

             })
                     .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                 {
                     progress.dismiss();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             });
            }
         else
             {

                 progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reached the maximum limit of attempts\n Try later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }



     }
 });
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

}
}

Academic.java

```
public class Academic extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
Bundle bundle;
String regno,dept;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_academic);

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

 /*Bundle arrives from Login Activity
    with Regno and dept
    Error raises due to the following three lines
  */
 bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 regno =bundle.getString("regno");
 dept=bundle.getString("dept");        //bundle receiving ends here

    //Tool bar declaration
    Toolbar toolbarObj = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarObj);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Academics");

    //Drawer Layout
    mDrawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //-----navigation selection
    NavigationView nv=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.select_nav_option);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case(R.id.academic):
                {
                    finish();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Academic.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;
                }
                case(R.id.logout):
                {
                    finish();
                    Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;

                }

                case(R.id.location):
                {

                    Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Location.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;

                }
                case(R.id.contact):
                {
                    finish();
                    Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Contact.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;

                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });




}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Logcat error

```
11-20 01:02:51.669 11153-11153/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk     W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
11-20 01:02:51.671 11153-11153/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk, PID: 11153
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk.Academic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk.Academic.onCreate(Academic.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-20 01:03:21.674 11153-11169/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: exiting
11-20 01:03:21.675 11153-11169/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: bye!
```

Help me...Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Logcat error posted.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting this error?

Comment: check Academics.java file the bundle line throws an error. Error lines were mentioned in the program comment

Comment: It means that your Bundle is `null`. Are you sure you are storing something in it?

Comment: Check the MainActivity.java  storing regno and dept into the bundle and retrieving in Academics.java